# Add custom header in Selenium and Sauce Labs?

Tags: selenium, user-agent

I use Selenium and Sauce Labs for testing.

Is there a Selenium property to add a custom header or append a string to the user agent (like "using Sauce Labs")?

I want to selectively not load some content for Selenium, because it is causing the units tests to be too finicky.  I have some widgets on the page, and sometimes the page doesn't complete loading... so I want to selectively not display them for Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Sauce Labs, but you can certainly do this on some Selenium setups, by changing the `general.useragent.override`, as follows (which may be adaptable):

Using the FirefoxDriver [you can](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addAdditionalPreference("general.useragent.override", "some UA string");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

with Cabybara [you can](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/03/configuring-user-agents-with-capybara-selenium-webdriver/):

```
Capybara.register_driver :iphone do |app|
  require 'selenium/webdriver'
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile['general.useragent.override'] = "iPhone"

  Capybara::Driver::Selenium.new(app, :profile => profile)
end
```