# Send identifiable "header" via Selenium HTML for Log Files

Tags: selenium

Is there a  way to send a header via a Selenium HTML script so that calls from the script can be easily identifiable in server log files?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Call the `addCustomRequestHeader(headerName, headerValue)` method to set the header and use one of the proxied browser choices (*e.g.*, "iexploreproxy").  Selenium RC will add the specified header to each request it forwards to the application.

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of the Selenium is to act like a user would do - so I dont know if thats possible. But I have possible workaround for you:

Make Selenium script to open some of predefined page and here click on link which leads to the real thing. At server you will know, that everyone going here from the page is "robot"

Best is if that page is "hidden" behind your firewall, so there is no possibility for "normal" user to discover it. For example:

1. Go to http://192.178.0.12:8080/test
2. Click the link here
3. test app appears

Since the IP starting 192 can be only inside your network, you know, that it was someone from your network = selenium script

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the UA string to your liking as described in this question:

[Add custom header in Selenium and Sauce Labs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525852/add-custom-header-in-selenium-and-sauce-labs)